# Wordpress. Layered Popups. Кнопка отправить заявку и переход на страницу благодарности

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Wordpress. Тема Betheme.
Плагин Layered Popups для всплывающих форм.
При нажатии кнопки отправки заявки нужно чтобы одновременно перекидывало на страницу благодарности (facebook пиксель). Кто подскажет, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-нибудь поможет. В блок контент слоя.

```
<input type="button" value="клик" onclick="one(); two();" />

<script>
function one() {
    return ulp_subscribe(this);
}
function two() {
    window.open('http://example.com');
}
</script>
```